# Регулярные выражения.Взять часть из тестового сообщения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

> Подскажите как взять User 'wrong_user' login failed via HTTP из текста
> [system] 2018-12-05 19:26:56 User 'wrong_user' login failed via HTTP from какой то айпи. Пытался что то делать,но не могу как исключить нальные символы. Вместо **User 'wrong_user' login failed via HTTP** может быть любое текстовое сообщение. Нужно вытаскивать текст после времени и до слова from

```
[^\w\d-\s].+?(?=from)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот

```
User '[^']+' login failed via HTTP
```

Тест https://regexr.com/58nmq

После времени и до текста " from" (в результате берите значение захваченной группы)

```
(?:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} )(.+)(?: from)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/58no7

> [system] 2018-12-05 **19:26:56 User 'wrong_user' login failed via HTTP
> from** 192.168.0.1
> [system] 2018-12-05 **19:26:56 User 'hello' login
> failed via HTTP from** 192.168.0.2

Comment: он работает только для этого примера.а Если будет вот это  [system] 2018-12-05 19:26:56 Some error text HTTPS from какой то айпи,то он не не работает .Надо  именно брать текст после времени и до слова from

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов пажждите, в вопросе не было никакого HTTPS и Some error text, отредактируйте его, указав правильное условие